# gstreamear with appsink causes 'too much recursion' in gjs

Tags: javascript, recursion, gstreamer, gjs

I would like to use appsink in my gnome shell extension but it causes the error: 'JS ERROR: too much recursion'.

My code is quite simple:

```
                Gst.init(null);
                this._pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("bin");
        
                const src = Gst.ElementFactory.make("ximagesrc", "src");
                const convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "convert");
                const sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("appsink", "sink");
        
                this._pipeline.add(src);
                this._pipeline.add(convert);
                this._pipeline.add(sink);
        
                sink.set_property("emit-signals", true);
        
                sink.connect("new-sample", () => {
                    console.log("new-sample");
                });
        
                if (!src.link(convert) || !convert.link(sink)) {
                    console.log('GStreamer failed to link');
                }
                
                this._pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING);
```

I tried to add miscellaneous elements between src and sink like `queue` or remove the `videoconvert`. Everytime, I add the handler for `new-sample` signal the error 'JS ERROR: too much recursion' hits me.

Comment: This is a known problem: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/issues/557
(Maybe you can help investigate it?)